# Contour integration with singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to find some resources on deformation of contour and came across the following problem. I am not sure how I would go about it and would appreciate some help.

Let $\gamma$ be the closed curve with radius 3 centered at 0. Find
$$ \int_\gamma \frac{1}{z^2+1} dz. $$
My initial thoughts are partial fraction decomposition, so
$$ \frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{1}{2i} \left( \frac{1}{z-i} - \frac{1}{z+i} \right).$$
We can then integrate each term individually. Deforming the contour to a small circle around $i$ (resp. $-i$) we get that the integral is
$$\frac{1}{2i} \left( 2\pi i - 2\pi i \right) = 0.$$
This doesn't really make any sense to me though.

Comment: it is correct ${}{}$. Note that $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ has an antiderivative on $|z| > 1$ : $\arctan(z)$ (the correct branch, with a branch cut on $[-i,i]$)

Comment: This happens with any pairs of unique poles inside that contour because you can take the radius $R \to \infty$. In that case, you'll have
$\left\vert\int{\mathrm{d}z \over z^{2} + 1}\right\vert \sim {1 \over R}$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: @FelixMarin Why doesn't that radius arguemnt work for $1/z$ then?

Comment: @user321210 Because, in that case, the integral magnitude is $\sim {1 \over R^{\color{#f00}{\large 0}}}$ as $R \to \infty$.